# Pandas merge creating weird characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes that are pretty straightforward - each contains 6 columns of text. When I do the merge, I'm getting a remarkable number of records that will not merge because of mysterious special characters that do not appear in the initial dataframes, but do appear in the now merged frame. For example, initially both dataframes will look like the starter. However, when I try to perform my merge, there will be several records on "right-only" dataset that now have mysterious characters appear. As a result, they will not merge. For example:

STARTER (both datasets)

```
merge_year merge_mo merge_day merge_st  merge_name    merge_county
1901       1        2         AL          BOONEY        ELMORE
1907       1        3         AL          MOVES         COVINGTON
1938       1        4         AL          JACK ROVERS   COVINGTON
```

Dataframe #1 after merge (left-only)

```
merge_year merge_mo merge_day merge_st  merge_name    merge_county
1901       1        2         AL          BOONEY        ELMORE
1907       1        3         AL          MOVES         COVINGTON
1938       1        4         AL          JACK ROVERS   COVINGTON
```

Dataframe #2 after merge (right-only)

```
merge_year merge_mo merge_day merge_st  merge_name      merge_county
1901       1        2         AL        ‚Äî BOONEY      ELMORE¬†
1907       1        3         AL        ‚Äî MOVES       COVINGTON¬†
1938       1        4         AL        JACK ROVERS     COVINGTON¬†
```

Now the shape of my resulting dataframe is 6,6 when it should be only 3 records long.

My code is really straight forward:

```
new_file3 = pd.merge(set1_merge, set2_merge, how='outer', validate='many_to_many', on=['merge_year','merge_mo','merge_day','merge_state','merge_name'], indicator=True)
```

Any tips here? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to remove the bad characters? Can't tell much more from what you've posted..

Comment: Perhaps you have some non-displayable characters or mixed encodings.  What do you get if you run `df.merge_name.encode('ascii')` on each DataFrame?

Comment: Yeah, it could be that the 2 datasets are being read in with different encodings. If setting the encoding as "ascii" on the merge doesn't work, try to set the encoding as ascii or utf8 (or other) when you read them in with pandas.read_excel or read_csv.